# Plotly installed, but VSCode doesn't seem to think so

Tags: visual-studio-code, plotly

I'm trying to learn how to use Plotly using VSCode, but the minute I run my code from the terminal, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'` Any idea why this is happening? Python is installed via Anaconda, and if I try to do `pip install plotly` it tells me it's already installed. I've tried nearly everything I can find about this issue and nothing works. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'll also add that when I do `pip install plotly` it gives the following:

`Requirement already satisfied: plotly in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.14.3) Requirement already satisfied: retrying>=1.3.3 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from plotly) (1.3.3) Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from plotly) (1.15.0)`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have multiple python versions installed and pip installed plotly for the wrong version. Try to do `pip --version` and in your code (before the plotly import) do

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

to see if the python versions match. If they don't, you may have to call `pip3 install` instead.

(Would have posted this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried that it's showing pip 20.2.3 from an Anaconda path with Python 3.8, and when I do the import sys thing it tells me Python 3.8.5.

Comment: Does this problem also occur with other packages unrelated to plotly? Choose some trending project from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/), install it the same way and see if it works. Before installing, make sure that the package is not already available (try to import it in your code and verify that it fails). This will help narrow down the issue. You can uninstall the new package afterwards with `pip uninstall`.

Comment: I tried all that. It recognizes things like numpy and pandas, just not plotly. I actually found a fix which I will put as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Accidental fix found: I was working with the bash shell on the VS Code terminal. I switched to the zsh shell by doing `exec zsh`. When I ran the file using the zsh shell, everything worked.